# How to properly install Protocol Compiler for pre-built binary?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protoc

I tried many times installing, "protoc-3.2.0-windows-x86_64.exe", but it doesn't get installed. When I double-click on it, there would be no screen displayed. I tried opening it through command line interface. I got a message as "Missing Input File".
[Protoc Installation Error on Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Kff.jpg)

What is that missing input file? What should I do now? Please respond to my problem at the earliest!

Comment: normally google supply the protoc program as a standalone program and not an installer. Try `protoc-3.2.0-windows-x86_64.exe -h`. you might find that protoc-3.2.0-windows-x86_64.exe is the protoc program. If so add it to your path

Comment: You advised me to add it my path. Where should I add it?

Comment: You have 2 options, add the directory where the `protoc` program is to the path variable or move the `protoc` to a directory on the existing path. This site http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/ shows you how to update the path variable (you can also get a list of directories on the path as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protoc-3.2.0-windows-x86_64.exe` *is* the Protocol Compiler. It is not an installer. This is the program itself.

This program is designed to run on the command line. It takes a `.proto` file as input (which you specify on the command line) and it outputs code in a variety of languages. It says "Missing input file" because you didn't specify a `.proto` file.

To "install" it, copy the `.exe` file to wherever you want to run it from. You may want to rename it to `protoc.exe`, and place it somewhere in your `PATH`, so that the command you have to type becomes just `protoc`.

Comment: Shall I place it in Anaconda3 directory? Because I want to install protocol buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The binary has to be placed in the path specified by Command Prompt, when opened under Admin mode. For me, under Admin mode, it was "C:/Windows/System32".